# How to call web service from java code?

Tags: java, web-services

I want to call a web service "gatewaedi" from java code.

I am not getting how to call it, could someone please provide an example?

Comment: Check the apache cxf project. http://cxf.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you call a webservice with JAX-RPC**

```
String wsdlURL = "http://localhost:6080/HelloWebService/services/Hello?wsdl"[1];

String namespace = "http://Hello.com"[2];

String serviceName = "GatewaediWebService";

QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);

ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();

Service service = serviceFactory.createService(serviceQN);
```

1. Should be replaced by the gatewaedi webservice call, which I can not find now.
2. Should be replaced by the gatewaedi webservice corresponding namespace, that too I can't find.

If you want send me more information about this webservice and I will write you the complete code.

Comment: "https://services.gatewayedi.com/eligibility/service.asmx?wsdl" this is my wsdl. And i want to call methods of this web service.